# htaccess redirect one page to another page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, jomres

i want to redirect this page https://www.example.com/index.php/en/component/jomres/?Itemid=0&task=search&page=1&towns%5B0%5D=calangute-goa

to another page
https://www.example.com/index.php/en/component/jomres/?Itemid=0&task=search&page=1&countries%5B0%5D=in

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution

```
Redirect /olddirectory/oldfile.html http://example.com/newdirectory/newfile.html
```

And here is the link, to refer [.htaccess Redirect](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file)

**EDIT 1**

In order to redirect the Requests, you need to enable the proxy module, and the proxy_http_module in the config files And then, you use

```
RewriteRule towns%5B0%5D countries%5B0%5D [NC,P]
```

Comment: did u enable proxy module and proxy_http_module ?

Comment: $proxy_enable = '0';